# Designing reusable game/chat server

Tags: c#, design, architecture, object-oriented-design, class-design

I'm encountering difficulties with making a reusable design for a game server in C#. Are there better architectural or design patterns that could be used here?

If I group similar system functionality, it would look something like this:

- Game (common for multiple types of games)

  - Add player: the player is created with some initialization info (player name), is added to the player list, and is sent a welcome message with the current game state. All other players are notified that the current player has joined. The current player is initially active if there is space and the game allows it, otherwise a spectator.
  - Remove player: the player is deleted, and all other players are notified that the player left
  - Spectate: change a player to be a spectator
  - Unspectate: change a player to active
- PlayerState (common for multiple types of games)

  - name (string)
  - active (bool): active if true, spectating if false
- TurnBasedGame

  - state (enum): active, inactive, intermission
  - move deadline (DateTime or DateTimeOffset): used for enforcing move time limits
  - if inactive and enough players join, enter intermission state
  - if in intermission for enough time, become active
  - if in intermission and too many players leave, become inactive
  - when game ends, enter intermission
- RealTimeGame

  - updateInterval (TimeSpan): updates the game at this interval
  - networkUpdateInterval (TimeSpan): sends current state to all players at this interval
- Chat

  - rate limit (TimeSpan)
  - Send: if allowed by the rate limit, the message is broadcast to all players, and the last send time is updated
- ChatPlayerState

  - last chat message send time (DateTime)

There are different types of games (`TicTacToeGame`, `ChessGame`, etc.), each of which is a combination of multiple above types (`Game`, `Chat`, `TurnBasedGame`) and extra state and operations specific to that game. It would also have a specific `SpecificGamePlayerState`, with player state specific to that game.

One server would be compiled for each specific game. In Visual Studio, the solution would include one project per game, which includes the game-specific code with a reference to a shared project. The entry point is a class that overrides the networking framework's methods for join, leave, message received. Those methods have a framework-specific player object as a parameter, which has a method to send messages using a framework-specific message object. My idea is that the entry point class would implement the specific functions for dealing with the framework, to decouple the framework from the `SpecificGame` classes, which contain only game logic and could be reused for other frameworks.

I've tried designing a generic class `Game<TPlayer>`, but in its method to add a player, it needs to send the current game state to the new players. If `Game` has a field with a `List<TPlayer>`, it would have to be shared with the concrete games (public getter, or protected field if inheritance is used), which is not good for encapsulation. Generating the welcome message can't be done in `Game`, so it would have to call a method in an interface `IWelcomeProducer<TWelcomeMessage>`, but this would add extra generic type parameters to `Game` for the message type.
Also, the concrete classes need to inherit multiple classes (like `Game`, `TurnBasedGame`, and `Chat`), so single inheritance wouldn't be enough. With a "composition over inheritance" design where the game-specific classes instantiate those types in private fields, the game and player state classes have to implement large interfaces with lots of delegation (forwarding methods), which results in lots of glue code.

With a naive design, it's possible to implement everything in one class for each game, but that would be the god class anti-pattern with code duplication between different games. Splitting that up into the modules described above seems to require macros, multiple inheritance, or mixins, but in single-inheritance languages that don't have those features, this might require reflection or code generation, like T4 templates (Text Template Transformation Toolkit).

Is there a way to implement this in a way that is type-safe (at compile time) and DRY (does not have lots of duplicated or unnecessary glue code) without resorting to reflection or code generation?

---

In code, this would look something like this:

Generic game code

```cs
public interface IWelcomeProducer<out W>
{
    W MakeWelcomeMessage();
}

public interface IPlayer<in J, in W>
{
    void Welcome(W welcomeInfo);
    void Join(int id, J joinInfo);
    void Leave(int id);
}

// J is the type of join info from clients
// W is the type of welcome message for clients
public class Game<J, W>
{
    private readonly IWelcomeProducer<W> welcomeProducer;
    private IPlayer<J, W>[] players;

    public Game(IWelcomeProducer<W> welcomeProducer) { /* ... */ }
    public int AddPlayer(IPlayer<J, W> player, J joinInfo) { /* ... */ }
    public void RemovePlayer(int id) { /* ... */ }
    public void Spectate(int id) { /* ... */ }
    public void Unspectate(int id) { /* ... */ }
}

public interface ITurnBasedPlayer
{
    void RoundInactive();
    void RoundIntermission(TimeSpan remaining);
    void RoundStart();
}

public class TurnBasedGame
{
    private ITurnBasedPlayer[] players;

    /* ... */
    public void AddPlayer(ITurnBasedPlayer player, J joinInfo, int id) { /* ... */ }
    public void RemovePlayer(int id) { /* ... */ }
}

public interface IChatClient
{
    void SendChatMessage(int sender, string message);
}

public class ChatBroadcast
{
    // To avoid having to expose AddPlayer and RemovePlayer methods,
    // we can reuse the player list from the concrete game
    private readonly IEnumerable<IChatClient> clients;

    public ChatBroadcast(IEnumerable<IChatClient> clients) { /* ... */ }
    public void ProcessChatMessage(int sender, string message) { /* ... */ }
}

public class ChatRateLimit
{
    /* ... */
    public bool CanSendChat(DateTime now) { /* ... */ }
    public void ChatSent(DateTime now) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Specific games

```cs
public interface IConcretePlayerClient :
    IPlayer<ConcreteJoinInfo, ConcreteWelcomeInfo>,
    ITurnBasedPlayer,
    IChatClient
{
    void SendMove(/*...*/);
}

public class ConcreteGame : IWelcomeProducer<ConcreteWelcomeInfo>
{
    private ConcretePlayer[] players;
    private BaseGame<ConcreteJoinInfo, ConcreteWelcomeInfo> game;
    private TurnBasedGame turnBasedGame;
    private ChatBroadcast chat = new ChatBroadcast(this.players);

    /* ... constructor ... */

    public ConcreteWelcomeInfo MakeWelcomeMessage() { /* ... */ }

    /* These forwarding methods have to be repeated in every concrete Game class */
    public int AddPlayer(/* ... */)
    {
        int id = game.AddPlayer(/* ... */);
        turnBasedGame.AddPlayer(/*...*/);
        players[id] = new ConcretePlayer(/**/);
    }
    public void RemovePlayer(int id) {
        game.RemovePlayer(id);
        turnBasedGame.RemovePlayer(id);
        players[id] = null;
    }
    /* ... other forwarding methods ... */
    public void ProcessChatMessage(int sender, string msg) { chat.ProcessChatMessage(sender, msg); }
    /* ... other forwarding methods ... */
}

public class ConcretePlayer
{
    public int ConcreteData { get; set; }

    private ChatRateLimit chatRateLimit;
    private IConcretePlayerClient client;

    public ConcretePlayer(int id, IConcretePlayerClient client) { /* ... */ }
    /* ... forwarding methods ... */
}
```

Entry points (this part can be changed if the framework changes, while the code above stays unchanged)

```cs
class FrameworkConcretePlayer : FrameworkPlayer, IConcretePlayerClient
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    /* implement methods by calling framework method to send over network */
}

class FrameworkConcreteGame : FrameworkGame<FrameworkConcretePlayer>
{
    private ConcreteGame game;
    /* ... constructor ... */
    public override void UserJoined(FrameworkConcretePlayer player)
    {
        player.ClientID = game.AddPlayer(player, player.JoinData);
    }
    public override void UserLeft(FrameworkConcretePlayer player)
    {
        game.RemovePlayer(player.ClientID);
    }
    public override void GotMessage(FrameworkConcretePlayer player, FrameworkMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Type)
        {
            /* call corresponding game method */
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid writing so much boilerplate (the forwarding methods), multiple inheritance/mixins/traits would seem to help, but those are not available in C# (default interfaces implementation are not available for .NET Framework yet).

It's probably possible to use reflection to create utilities to reduce boilerplate, but this might result in runtime errors, so it is not completely type-safe.

I could use code generation to generate `FrameworkConcreteGame` for each game, which would rely on the code generation tool to reuse code. Also, the code will be type-checked by the compiler.

Comment: A practical code example would do wonders here. It's hard to blindly trust a written text about intentions - maybe you made a wrong choice, or made the right choice but phrased something wrongly, or I just misread it. Code, however, is much less open to these kinds of misinterpretations.

Comment: @Flater, I have added some code to supplement the written text.